# Finding records over continuous date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query which returns loans that have been taken in a semester, the semesters are defined in this way:

```
Jan - April - Spring
May - August - Summer
September - Dec - Fall
```

Now my loans can start at any time and can span for any duration of time:
say a loan starts in Dec 2013 to Oct 2014, then the loan has spanned the four semesters:

```
Fall 2013
Spring 2014
Summer 2014
Fall 2014
```

And so when counting the number of loans for each semester for each year, the count of this loan will be present in all the four semesters

```
Fall 2013
Spring 2014
Summer 2014
Fall 2014
```

The schema of the loan table is

```
LOAN(Loan_ID, St_id@, Comp_id@, Start_Date, Date_Returned)
```

where start_date and date_returned are the corresponding start and end dates of a loan.
What I have so far does not take into account loans that have overlapped into semesters.

```
SELECT extract(YEAR FROM start_date) AS year,
       CASE WHEN extract(MONTH FROM start_date) <= 4 THEN 'spring'
            WHEN extract(MONTH FROM start_date) > 4 AND extract(MONTH FROM start_date) <=8 THEN 'summer'
            ELSE 'fall' END AS semester,
       Count(comp_id) AS num_of_loans
FROM loan
GROUP BY (extract(YEAR FROM start_date), 
          CASE WHEN extract(MONTH FROM start_date) <= 4 THEN 'spring'
          WHEN extract(MONTH FROM start_date) > 4 AND extract(MONTH FROM start_date) <=8 THEN 'summer'
          ELSE 'fall' END)
ORDER BY YEAR, Decode(semester, 'spring', 1, 'summer', 2, 'fall', 3);
```

Sample Input:

```
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L101', '101', 'H101', TO_DATE('2014-10-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L102', '102', 'H101', TO_DATE('2014-10-31','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-11-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L103', '102', 'H102', TO_DATE('2014-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L104', '101', 'H102', TO_DATE('2014-10-31','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-11-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L105', '102', 'H102', TO_DATE('2014-11-04','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-11-10','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L106', '103', 'N101', TO_DATE('2014-10-15','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-20','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L107', '201', 'N101', TO_DATE('2013-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-09-19','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L108', '201', 'N102', TO_DATE('2013-11-15','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L109', '202', 'N102', TO_DATE('2013-10-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-10-19','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L110', '202', 'N102', TO_DATE('2013-08-23','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-09-02','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L111', '202', 'N104', TO_DATE('2014-11-12','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-11-15','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L112', '203', 'N104', TO_DATE('2014-08-27','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-08-31','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L113', '301', 'N104', TO_DATE('2014-09-13','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-09-23','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L114', '301', 'N104', TO_DATE('2014-10-23','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L115', '301', 'N107', TO_DATE('2014-10-11','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-14','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L116', '302', 'N107', TO_DATE('2014-09-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-09-15','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L117', '101', 'H101', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L118', '101', 'H103', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L119', '101', 'H104', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L120', '101', 'H103', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L121', '101', 'H104', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L122', '101', 'H105', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L123', '101', 'H106', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L124', '101', 'H106', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
INSERT INTO loan VALUES('L125', '101', 'H105', TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null);
```

Sample Output:

```
SEMESTER    YEARS   NUM_LOANS
Spring      2013    0
Summer      2013    3
Fall        2013    5
Spring      2014    1
Summer      2014    2
Fall        2014    20
```

what I get:

```
YEAR    SEMESTER    NUM_OF_LOANS
2013        summer  2
2013        fall    3
2014        summer  1
2014        fall    19
```

Thanks!

Comment: please make it question clear.

Comment: I am sorry but which part is unclear, I would like to clarify that in much detail. Regards.

Comment: what is the expected output you need

Comment: What i noted is, in your sample output, how did you get an entry of Spring 2014 ?? Spring is the semester whose month is <=4 but in your sample input there is no entry of such a start_date.

Comment: @AakankshaShah you are correct that there is no entry for that in my records, but what is happening is there is one loan that is being carried over from previous semester into the spring semester, so the count of loans for those two semesters would be incremented by 1, because this loan is present in both the semesters, that is why in my output you dont see any spring entry, but in correct output there is a spring entry

Answer (score 2):

### Query ::

```
WITH FNL AS(

  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.START_DATE) AS YEAR,B.SEMESTER AS semester,0 as num_of_loans

  FROM LOAN A,(SELECT 1 SEQ,'spring' SEMESTER,0 NUM_OF_LOANS FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT 2,'summer' SEMESTER,0 num_of_loans from dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 3,'fall' SEMESTER ,0 num_of_loans FROM DUAL) b
  GROUP BY B.SEMESTER,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM START_DATE)

  union all 


  SELECT extract(YEAR FROM start_date) AS year,
         CASE WHEN extract(MONTH FROM start_date) <= 4 THEN 'spring'
              WHEN extract(MONTH FROM start_date) > 4 AND extract(MONTH FROM start_date) <=8 THEN 'summer'
              ELSE 'fall' END AS semester,
         Count(comp_id) AS num_of_loans
  FROM loan
  GROUP BY (extract(YEAR FROM start_date), 
            CASE WHEN extract(MONTH FROM start_date) <= 4 THEN 'spring'
            WHEN extract(MONTH FROM start_date) > 4 AND extract(MONTH FROM start_date) <=8 THEN 'summer'
            ELSE 'fall' END)

)
select year,semester,sum(num_of_loans) from fnl group by year,semester 
ORDER BY YEAR, Decode(semester, 'spring', 1, 'summer', 2, 'fall', 3);
```

---

```
Output :
Year    semester  num_of_loans
2013    spring        0
2013    summer        1
2013    fall          3
2014    spring        0
2014    summer        1
2014    fall         20
```

i hope this helpful for you.Good Luck.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have an operating SQL Server available at the moment, but I believe it should look something like this:

```
select  @min = min(start_date),
        @max = max(end_date)
FROM LOAN

SELECT  @minYear = YEAR(@min),
        @minSem  = CEILING(MONTH(@min)/4),
        @maxYear = YEAR(@max),
        @maxSem  = CEILING(MONTH(@max)/4),
        @semCount= (4-@minSem+@maxSem)+(@maxYear-@minYear-1)*3,
        @i       = 0

 CREATE TABLE #TMP (Semester INT, Year INT, LoanCount INT)

 WHILE @i < @semCount BEGIN
     SELECT @curSem = (@minSem + @i)%3, -- 3 semesters per year
            @curYear = @minYear + FLOOR((@minSem +@i)/3)

     INSERT INTO #TMP
        SELECT @curSem,
                @curYear,
                (SELECT COUNT * FROM LOAN 
                   WHERE YEAR(end_date) >= @curYear
                   AND CEILING(MONTH(end_date)/4)>+@curSem
                   YEAR(start_date) <= @curYear
                   AND CEILING(MONTH(start_date)/4)<=@curSem) as loanCount

     SELECT @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #TMP
```

Hope this helps.  Good Luck

Comment: thank you for the response, I am working on oracle 11g

Comment: Ah.  Sorry, I didn't notice the tag.  Unfortunately, I don't know Oracle syntax, but the concepts should be translatable.  In any case, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join semestrs with loans, here's a brief example:

```
    with loan as (
        -- This is your sample data
        select  TO_DATE('2014-10-19','YYYY-MM-DD') startdate, TO_DATE('2014-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD') datereturned from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-10-31','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-11-03','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all       
        select  TO_DATE('2014-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-30','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-10-31','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-11-03','YYYY-MM-DD')        from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-04','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-11-10','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all 
        select  TO_DATE('2014-10-15','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-20','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2013-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-09-19','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2013-11-15','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2013-10-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-10-19','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2013-08-23','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2013-09-02','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-12','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-11-15','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-08-27','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-08-31','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-09-13','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-09-23','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-10-23','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-10-11','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-10-14','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-09-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2014-09-15','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null from dual union all
        select  TO_DATE('2014-11-19','YYYY-MM-DD'), null FROM dual
        ),
    timescale as ( -- Timescale  boundaries to build a list of semesters
        select  to_date ('01.01.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy') d1,    -- Start date
                to_date ('01.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy') d2     -- End date
        from dual
    ),
    months as (  -- List of months withing the timescale , semestr is specified for each month
        select  y || '*' ||
                case 
                    when m < 5 then 'Spring'
                    when m > 8 then 'Fall'
                    else            'Summer'
                end s,
                d d1,
                add_months(d,1)-1 d2         
        from (
            select  add_months (d1, level-1) d,
                    extract (year from  add_months (d1, level-1)) y,
                    extract (month from  add_months (d1, level-1)) m
            from timescale
            connect by add_months (d1, level-2) < d2
          )
    ),
    semestr as( -- List of semesters with their boundaries, built by grouping the list of months 
        select s, min(d1) d1, max(d2) d2
        from months
        group by s
    )
    -- the query itself - quite easy
    select  s,
           (select count(1) from loan where startdate <= d2 and nvl(datereturned, d1) >= d1 ) x
    from    semestr
    order by d1
```